# Assembly - Extract a field from a register

Tags: assembly, sparc

I have an assembly assignment and are having issues trying t work the problem's logic.  I was hoping that someone could help me get started in this.  The program has to be written in assembly code.

PROBLEM:

Write assembly program to extract a field from register %l0.
The position of the least significant bit is to be specified in register %l2
and the number of bits in the field in register %l3.
The result of executing your program is to extract the field specified from register
%l0, storing the field in %l1.

Hint: Use logical operators like and, or, etc and bit shifting operators.

Please use these macro definitions:

define(num_r, l0)   ! the number
define(field_r, l1) ! the extracted field
define(org_r, l2)   ! least significant bit of field
define(width_r, l3) ! width of field
define(mask_r, l4)  ! bit mask

Example 1

mov     0xfff, %num_r
mov     2, %org_r
mov     3, %width_r

answer: 111  (this is 7 in decimal)

Comment: You forgot to mention the architecture. Anyway, as the hint says, just do a shift left to get rid of the unneeded top bits, then a shift right to get rid of the unneeded low bits and align the result.

Comment: SPARC architecture.   I'll try that.  Thanks